# record edit form onSubmit is not called after installing component through package in another sandbox from a sandbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, salesforce1-app, lightning-community

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"
            access="global"
            controller="BOM_Item_Component_Controller" >
<aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="errMsg" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="class" type="String" default="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfTextChildBOM" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfInputChildBOM" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfCancelChildBOM" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfTextProduct" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfInputProduct" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfCancelProduct" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfTextProductF" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfInputProductF" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfCancelProductF" type="String" default="slds-hide" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfChildBOM" type="String" default="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfProduct" type="String" default="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1" />
<aura:attribute name="classOfProductFamily" type="String" default="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="modelHeading" type="String" default="New Item"/>
<aura:attribute name="buttonLabel" type="String" default="Save"/>
<aura:attribute name="BOMId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name = "tableHeight" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="showRowNumberColumn" type="Boolean" />
<!-- This attribute will hold the update records from data table-->
<aura:attribute name="updatedRecord" type="Object[]" />
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.isRefreshed}" />
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form" objectApiName="HS_Sales__Bill_Of_Materials_Item__c" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" recordId="{!v.BOMId}">
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Start ######-->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                          onclick="{!c.cancel }"
                                          alternativeText="close"
                                          variant="bare-inverse"
                                          class="slds-modal__close"/>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">{!v.modelHeading}</h2>
                </header>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.errMsg != ''}">
                    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error">{!v.errMsg}</div>
                </aura:if>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <div class="{!v.class}"><lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" aura:id="Name" /></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfTextChildBOM}" style="padding-top:10px"><a href ="#" onclick ="{!c.CreateChildBOM}"><ui:outputText value="Create New Child BOM"/></a></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfCancelChildBOM}" style="padding-top:10px"><a href ="#" onclick ="{!c.CancelCreateChildBOM}"><ui:outputText value="Cancel"/></a></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfInputChildBOM}"><lightning:input label="Child BOM" aura:id="inputChildBOM" /></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfChildBOM}"><lightning:inputField aura:id="childBOM" fieldName="HS_Sales__Child_BOM__c" class="ggg"/></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfTextProduct}" style="padding-top:10px"><a href ="#" onclick ="{!c.CreateProduct}"><ui:outputText value="Create New Product"/></a></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfCancelProduct}" style="padding-top:10px"><a href ="#" onclick ="{!c.CancelCreateProduct}"><ui:outputText value="Cancel"/></a></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfInputProduct}"><lightning:input label="Product" aura:id="inputProduct" /></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfProduct}"><lightning:inputField aura:id="product" fieldName="HS_Sales__Product__c" /></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfTextProductF}" style="padding-top:10px"><a href ="#" onclick ="{!c.CreateProductFamily}"><ui:outputText value="Create New Product Family"/></a></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfCancelProductF}" style="padding-top:10px"><a href ="#" onclick ="{!c.CancelCreateProductFamily}"><ui:outputText value="Cancel"/></a></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfInputProductF}"><lightning:input label="Product Family" aura:id="inputProductFamily" /></div>
                    <div class="{!v.classOfProductFamily}"><lightning:inputField aura:id="productFamily" fieldName="HS_Sales__Product_Family__c" /></div>
                    <div class="{!v.class}" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px"><lightning:inputField fieldName="HS_Sales__Required__c" /></div>
                    <div class="{!v.class}"><lightning:inputField fieldName="HS_Sales__Sort_Order__c" /></div>
                    <div class="slds-hide"><lightning:inputField aura:id="BOM" fieldName="HS_Sales__Bill_Of_Materials__c" /></div>

            </div>
            <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="{!v.buttonLabel}" />
                <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancel}"/>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:if>


<!-- You must define keyField as 'Id' to save the record back in Salesforce

 <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
    <h1 class="slds-text-heading_large">Bill Of Material Items</h1>
</div>-->
<div align = "center" style="padding-bottom:10px" >
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="New Item" onclick="{!c.openModel}"/>
</div>
<div style="height: 700px">
    <lightning:datatable
                         aura:id="BOMItemDataTable"
                         columns="{! v.columns }"
                         data="{! v.data }"
                         keyField="Id"
                         onsave ="{!c.onSave}"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                         onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                         maxColumnWidth="350" 
                         minColumnWidth="10"
                         />

</div>
```

Comment: Did you check in console you might getting some exception?

Comment: yeah i checked no error in console @TusharSharma